# upload porto theme with existing database in Magento 2.3.5

Tags: magento2.3, database, theme, porto-theme, porto

can I upload the porto theme and use my old products hence the dummy data will be removed and my old data will be shown... is this possiable
furthermore will my old categories appear in the theme or will I have to make new ones. I've read the documentation it did say its possible but the method and definition was ambiguous. so pleas let me know so that i could change my magento theme.
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can change your theme without losing products or categories as the theme is completely separate to them. You should see the exact same categories and products in the new theme.

Comment: should I just upload the theme which consist of app and pub folder ?

Comment: Just the app/design/frontend area, Magento will populate the pub folder automatically with the files needed